# How to show that a leaf is topologically a cone.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I am trying to understand the topological behaviour of foliations around irreducible singularities, specially in the case of singularities in the Poincaré domain. I am using the  third chapter of this text: [Singular Points of Analytic Differential Equations](http://indico.ictp.it/event/a0245/contribution/3/material/0/0.pdf).

My question is about a consequence of Proposition (1.1) oh Chapter III, which says that, given $\omega_0=\lambda xdy-\mu ydx$ with $\lambda \mu \ne 0$, $\lambda / \mu \notin \mathbb{R}^-$, then

1) The leaves of $\omega_0=0$ are transverse to the centered spheres.

2) There exists a real linear flow whose trajectories are contained in the leaves of $\omega_0=0$ and for which $(0,0)$ is an attractor.

A consequence of this result is the following:

(*) Every leaf is topologically a cone with vertex $(0,0)$ and whose directrix is its intersection with the unit sphere.

This fact is not difficult to visualize thinking the problem in 3 dimensions, but I am not sure of the correct way to show it, so my question is how to write the proof of (*) formally.